# Array of pointers that point to structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

My structure is this:

```
typedef struct celltag{
    char name[11];
    double time;
    struct celltag *next;
} celltype;
```

And structures of this type are saved in a array of linked lists:

```
typedef celltype **Hash;
```

and two structures X and Y are linked into the same list if, for some given function `h(char x[]), h(X->name)=h(Y->name)`. What I'm trying to say is that these structures are sorted into the array by their 'names'.

Now, I have to sort the structures by their 'time' using array of pointers such that the first pointer in the array points to the structure with the smallest time, the second pointer to the second smallest etc.

How do I do that? I'm still not very good with pointers so I don't know how to approach this at all. I tried looking at the similar questions already posted here but the pointers completely baffle me and I can't seem to make them work for my code.

For example, if I have a function:

```
void sort(Hash A, celltype *PArray[MAX]){
}
```

where `*PArray[MAX]` is my array of pointers and Hash A is where the structures are stored. How do I write the rest of function? How to make a pointer point to a structure??

Comment: That's a really tiny buffer for `name`. You sure `char*` with a dynamically allocated buffer isn't a better idea?

Comment: @tadman Yes, in the assignment it's specified that name won't have more than 10 chars.

Comment: Answer: `qsort`. Write a compare function that returns the results of `(a > b) - (a < b)` where `a` and `b` are your `celltype->time` members. Then set a pointer to each of your `struct` from your hash table (remembering to chain through any `celltype` that are held in a linked list due to a hash collision on storage). Then just call `qsort` on the array of pointers to sort the pointers in order of `celltype->time` ascending.

Comment: That's one way to teach students about buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck, the overview of what you will need to do is iterate over your hash table (i.e. over each bucket and then over each node of the list contained in each bucket to make your array of pointers point to each entry in your hash table. It doesn't matter how you hash table is keyed, all you care about is making each used pointer in `PArray` point to a `celltype`.

I presume you know how to iterate over your hash table. Just loop from `0` to `ht_size` (where `htsize` is the number of buckets, e.g. array elements, in your hash table). You then simply declare a `celltype *p` pointer and iterate the list pointed to by the bucket entry (which can just be a single `celltype*` where the `next` pointer is `NULL`, or it could be any number based on the hash collision that resulted in more than one `celltype*` resolving to the bucket `hashtable[x]`)

Once you have filled `PArray` so that some number of pointers `nptr` now point to a `celltype*` in your hash table, all that remains is calling `qsort` to sort the pointers by the `celltype->time` member. The only trick is you must write the *compare* function to compare the adjacent `celltype->time` values.

The `qsort` compare function has the prototype:

```
int compare (const void *ap, const void *bp);
```

(where `a` and `b` are *pointers to* adjacent elements being compared. I added the `p` just to denote them as pointers)

What are we sorting? An *array of pointers* to `celltype`. So each member of the array is already a pointer, and if each parameter is a *pointer* to your adjacent elements, then each parameter will represent a *pointer to pointer to* `celltype`.

Once you have worked out what your *compare* pointers represent, it is just a matter of dereferencing the parameters to allow you to access the `time` member within each struct. When each parameter is a *pointer to pointer*, you can cast the parameter to `type * const *` and dereference to provide you with a *pointer to type* that you can use to compare the `time` values, e.g.

```
/* qsort compare for array of pointers to celltype */
int compare (const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
    celltype *a = *((celltype * const *)ap);
    celltype *b = *((celltype * const *)bp);

    return (a->time > b->time) - (a->time < b->time);
}
```

(for any numeric type, returning the result of the two conditionals `(a > b) - (a < b)` for an ascending sort, simply avoids potential overflow that could result if you return `a - b`, e.g. where `a` could be a large negative value and `b` a large positive value resulting in overflow)

While you don't show how `A` is declared, you do show the `typedef` for `Hash` that when dereferenced would result in a pointer to `celltype`. Using `ht_size` to represent the number of buckets in your hash table, your `sort` function would then look something like:

```
void sort(Hash A, celltype *PArray[MAX]){

    size_t nptr = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ht_size; i++) {  /* loop over buckets */
        celltype *p = A[i];                 /* pointer to celltype */
        while (p) {                         /* iterate over all chained nodes */
            PArray[nptr++] = p;             /* assigning pointer to PArray */
            p = p->next
        }
    }

    qsort (PArray, ntpr, sizeof *PArray, compare);   /* call qsort */
}
```

That's it in a nutshell. If your still having trouble wrapping your head around the `qsort` concept in the partial example above, a short full example should remove the confusion, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct celltag{
    char name[11];
    double time;
    struct celltag *next;
} celltype;

int compare (const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
    celltype *a = *((celltype * const *)ap);
    celltype *b = *((celltype * const *)bp);

    return (a->time > b->time) - (a->time < b->time);
}

int main (void) {

    celltype    c1 = { .name = "three", .time = 127.21 },
                c2 = { .name = "one", .time = 127.1 },
                c3 = { .name = "two", .time = 127.19 },
            *pc[] = { &c1, &c2, &c3 };
    size_t n = sizeof pc / sizeof *pc;

    qsort (pc, n, sizeof *pc, compare);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%-5s  %6.2f\n", pc[i]->name, pc[i]->time);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/qsort_ptp_struct
one    127.10
two    127.19
three  127.21
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.